# Which data processes are applied on FAERS data

Tags: openfda

I am trying to understand if the FAERS data are processed in OpenFDA similarly to what is done in softwares (RxLogix, ORACLE, CVW), meaning:

1. Have the FAERS data been checked for duplicates with duplication
   removal?
2. Have the MedDRA PT been mapped to the latest version of the MedDRA
   dictionary?
3. Have the drug names been cleaned?

I couldn't find any answer to these questions from OpenFDA website or from the article from Kass-Hout et al J Am Med Infrom Assoc 2016; 23: 596-600.

Please don't hesitate to redirect me to any formal documentation for any of these 3 questions above.

Answer (score 0):

> Please don't hesitate to redirect me to any formal documentation for
>   any of these 3 questions above.

I'd say the best place to find answers to these questions is the FAERS pipeline source code: https://github.com/FDA/openfda/blob/master/openfda/faers/pipeline.py